# Open ComboBox Dropdown of a ui5-combobox web component programmatically

Tags: combobox, web-component, ui5-webcomponents

Is there a way to open the dropdown of a [`<ui5-combobox>` web component](https://sap.github.io/ui5-webcomponents/playground/components/ComboBox/) programmatically?
What I found was a solution using a plain HTML combobox setting DroppedDown to true but this seems not to apply to the UI5 ComboBox web component.

What I'm looking for is to open the dropdown of the ComboBox when the user clicks in it or tabs into it.

Answer (score 0):

The element is different, but the solution should work.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('ui5-multi-combobox')[0].shadowRoot.querySelector("ui5-icon").click()
```